# How to raise exception in Coq?(in match ... end)

Tags: coq

I need to define recursive definitions, but I don't no yet how to do it correctly().
So I want to have partially defined function which will say when it need additional level of recursion to be written.

```
Context (qsigT: forall (A : Type) (P : forall a : A, Type), Type).
Context (qpr1: forall (A : Type) (P : forall a : A, Type), (@qsigT A P) -> A ).
Record Category :={
 ty:>Type
}.
Context (uc:Category).
Context (mO mS: uc -> Type).

 Definition ur0:= (@qsigT uc  (fun x => mO (x)                       ) ).
 Definition ur1:= (@qsigT ur0 (fun x => mS (qpr1 _ _ x)                   ) ).
 Definition ur2:= (@qsigT ur1 (fun x => mS (qpr1 _ _ (qpr1  _ _ x))             ) ).
 Definition ur3:= (@qsigT ur2 (fun x => mS (qpr1 _ _ (qpr1  _ _ (qpr1 _ _ x)))       ) ).
 (*and so on ...*)

 Definition ur (n: nat) := (match n with
  |0 => ur0
  |1 => ur1
  |2 => ur2
  |_ => ur3
  (*|_ => error*)
 end).
```

1)Is it possibly to create exception on all natural numbers greater than 3? (during the pattern matching)

2)Is there a low level instrument which will not coerce me to use monades?

3)Is it possibly to define my function 'ur' on all natural numbers in Coq?

4)Is there some kind of combinator that will apply function 'pr1' n times?

5)Shall I create 5 different question (with one on the meta :-) ) or it is right way to ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Is it possibly to create exception on all natural numbers greater
>     than 3? (during the pattern matching)

No. Coq is a total language. The standard pattern for this is to make your function to return `option T` for type `T`, so you work in a *partiality monad*. Example:

```
Definition ur (n: nat) := (match n with
  | 0 => Some ur0
  | 1 => Some ur1
  | 2 => Some ur2
  | 3 => Some ur3
  | _ => None
 end).
```

> 2) Is there a low level instrument which will not coerce me to use monads?

See above. Whether you want to call it "monad" or not is up to you.

Another approach is to have a "default" value `urF` that you return when you "fail" the pattern matching. This approach is more convenient than the option type in a wide variety of situations.

> 3) Is it possibly to define my function 'ur' on all natural numbers in Coq?

I think so. Please provide the missing definitions and we may try.

> 4) Is there some kind of combinator that will apply function 'pr1' n times?

In principle yes, but it'd depend on the exact type you want for it.

> 5) Shall I create 5 different question (with one on the meta :-) ) or it is right way to ask?

Maybe. The biggest problem of this question is that the code is not
self-contained.

Comment: For 1) we can also use inductive datatypes and do the work with relations, not functions.

Comment: Indeed! But you lose simplification on your definitions so this is a tradeoff that must be weighted carefully. In general I'd always prefer a Definition over an Inductive if the function is computable.

Comment: (3) I changed a code to make it self-contained. Thanks a lot for your correct answer to my previous question. It is problem to write the definition of 'ur' over all nat. I really need some help with it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've just noticed that I did a logical mistake, I will add another comment when it will be corrected.

Comment: Couldn't use use `admit` to simulate, e.g., Haskell's `undefined` behavior?

Comment: @k_g not exactly, specially in 8.5, but I guess that'd be a different question.